# Append one list and one tuple to list together as one list

Tags: python

I am proceeding two data from one my sql table as list which has three elements and the other as tuple which has 64 elements. I want to append them to a list like this one

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
a = cursor.fetchone()

listA = []

for row in rows:
    listA.append([list(a),list(row)])
print(listA)
```

This created three dimensional list. I want it to be 2D.

Like this,

```
a = ['url','name','id']
row = ['2012993','name','category', .... more 61 element]

listA = [[['url','name','id],['2012993',,'name','category',....more 61 elements]]]
```

But I want it like this

```
listA = [['url','name','id],['2012993',,'name','category',....more 61 elements]]]
```

Comment: Do you need all rows in one sublist?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending a list that contains the two lists, append each of the two lists separately:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
a = cursor.fetchone()

listA = []

for row in rows:
    listA.append(list(a))
    listA.append(list(row)])
print(listA)
```

If there are more than one row in `rows`, this will append `a` multiple times before each row. If that's what you want, great. If not, then you might want to move `listA.append(list(a))` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

from what I was able to understand you want to create a list like `[one_list(a,rows), one_list(a,rows)... etc]`  to do this you can do:

```
import numpy as np 

rows = cursor.fetchall()
a = cursor.fetchone()

listA = []

for row in rows:
    listA.append(np.concatenate([list(a),list(row)]))
print(listA)
```

your question is a bit confusing because there is a lot of mistakes but from what I understood this is what you wanted.